# Why does SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=? returns nothing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-batch, h2

I am testing a spring batch application witht he help of the Spring batch testing. I have created the tables that the spring batch test use manually in the h2 database. However when test launching a `Step` I am  getting the following error -

```
18:45:19.909 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.cache - Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@75b3ef1a size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 5, missCount = 1]
18:45:20.158 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource - Initializing lazy target object
18:45:20.163 [main] WARN  org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer - No transaction manager was provided, using a DataSourceTransactionManager
18:45:20.196 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
18:45:20.196 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql']
18:45:20.222 [main] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean - No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
18:45:20.956 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT]
18:45:20.956 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [create*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE]
18:45:20.956 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method [getLastJobExecution*] with attribute [PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE]
18:45:21.012 [main] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
18:45:21.020 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
18:45:21.021 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql']
18:45:21.042 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] for JDBC transaction
18:45:21.045 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Changing isolation level of JDBC Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to 8
18:45:21.045 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to manual commit
18:45:21.061 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
18:45:21.064 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
18:45:21.073 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
18:45:21.074 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA]
18:45:21.074 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting isolation level of JDBC Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to 2
18:45:21.074 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [conn5: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] after transaction
18:45:21.075 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
18:45:21.075 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql']
18:45:21.092 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] for JDBC transaction
18:45:21.092 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Changing isolation level of JDBC Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to 8
18:45:21.092 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to manual commit
18:45:21.092 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
18:45:21.092 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
18:45:21.093 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
18:45:21.093 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
18:45:21.102 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
18:45:21.102 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]
18:45:21.119 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
18:45:21.119 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
18:45:21.270 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
18:45:21.270 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]
18:45:21.273 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
18:45:21.273 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA]
18:45:21.274 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting isolation level of JDBC Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to 2
18:45:21.274 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [conn6: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] after transaction
18:45:21.277 [main] INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=TestJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
18:45:21.290 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Job execution starting: JobExecution: id=1, version=0, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Tue Aug 29 18:45:21 CEST 2023, status=STARTING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=1, version=0, Job=[TestJob]], jobParameters=[{}]
18:45:21.395 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource - Initializing lazy target object
18:45:21.396 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
18:45:21.396 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql']
18:45:21.408 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Acquired Connection [conn7: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] for JDBC transaction
18:45:21.408 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [conn7: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] to manual commit
18:45:21.415 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
18:45:21.415 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID=?]
18:45:21.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
18:45:21.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [conn7: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA]
18:45:21.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [conn7: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=SA] after transaction
18:45:21.419 [main] ERROR org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:880) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:906) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:307) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:174) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:443) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:315) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchJob(StepRunner.java:172) ~[spring-batch-test-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchStep(StepRunner.java:161) ~[spring-batch-test-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:251) ~[spring-batch-test-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(JobLauncherTestUtils.java:225) ~[spring-batch-test-4.3.8.jar:4.3.8]
    at BatchTest.testStep(BatchTest.java:152) ~[test-classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725) ~[junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:5.8.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:
```

I dont know why this query is not returning any value what it requires

```
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
```

My application-test.properties looks as follows -

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema.sql'
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

I have created the following schema for the BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE under the file `schema.sql` -

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
                                     JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
                                     VERSION BIGINT ,
                                     JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                                     JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
                                     constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
) ;
```

Comment: Please share the code that leads to that error: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you run the query manually against the database to verify that you do get data back?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to some internal classes of Spring Batch. Did you change the SpringBoot version ou do something like that?

First of all be sure you configured the DataSource, TransactionManager and JobRepository correctly.

Secondly, I faced this problem, and when I toggled a break point at the line I saw that the *id* parameter at `?` was set with 0 and the right job ID was a different value. This explains why the query returns nothing.
This wrong value setting happened due to the configurations aforementioned. I was migrating SpringBoot and some BeanFactory classes (such as MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean) got deprecated. After replacing the deprecated classes by the ones recommended at deprecation notes the problem got solved.